# Can one create a new goal for previous AdWords visitors if they now go to the goal page?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, conversions, goals

I know you cant create goals retrospectively in Analytics and AdWords.

But I have been converting most of my AdWords customers in my showroom, not online through the ecommerce part of the website. I now want them all to visit a certain page which I will set as a conversion goal.

Will the goals be recorded if I created this goal after they first got tagged via AdWords?
The actual goal completion will occur after I create the goal when they now visit this special conversion recording page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The goal will be recorded after:

1) creating a goal :)

2) completion of goal needs to fulfill condition e.g visit a specified page from specified source  (adwords campaign?)